# error failed to import bridging header となり Header ファイルを読み込めない

Tags: swift

XcodeとSwiftのバージョンアップを行ったら下記のスクリーンショットのエラーとなりビルドができなくなりました。

アップデート前の環境です。
　Xcodeのバージョンは7.2
　Swiftのバージョンは2.1.1

アップデート後の環境です。
　Xcodeのバージョンは8.1
　Swiftのバージョンは3.0.1
　cocoaPodsのバージョンは0.39.0

使用しているライブラリです。
　AWSCognito (2.4.9)
　AWSCore (2.4.9)
　AWSSNS (2.4.9)

build Settings -> Swift Compiler - General -> Object-C Bridging Headerのパスは正しい値が設定されています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: Bridging Headerの問題ではなくて、AWSCoreやAWSSNS（おそらくそれ以外も）などBridging Headerがインポートしているフレームワークでビルドエラーが起こってることが直接の原因ですね。ビルドエラーを解決してそれぞれのフレームワークが正しくビルドできれば直ります。現状でわかるのはそれだけですね。具体的にどう直すかは、個々のエラーを知る必要があり、エラーが多すぎるので、プロジェクトを丸ごと見せてもらう必要があります。可能ならどこかにアップロードしてください。

Comment: 早速の回答ありがとうございます。質問内にインポートしているフレームワークのバージョンも追記しました。プロジェクトをアップするのが厳しいので、、、他に必要と思われる情報等ありますでしょうか。